# Fancybox, iframe окно

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

На странице есть ссылка [http://мойсайт/index.php?id=20](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/index.php?id=20) при клике по ней всплывает fancybox с формой добавления, как запретить это окно открывать через -> правая кнопка мыши -> открыть ссылку в новом окне? Если это сделать будет голая некрасивая страница, на которой кроме формы ничего не будет.

Comment: можно поменять html, сделав кнопку не через `<a>`, а через `<button>`- по ней правый клик не работает

Comment: @lexxl можно конкретней, никогда fancybox через button не вызывал, но все же не прокатит так как ссылка текстовая, кнопку туда лепить не красиво будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элемент, по которому открывается попап fancybox'а совершенно необязательно должен быть ссылкой. Вы можете вообще открывать попап когда угодно, вызывая его напрямую.

Посмотрите на код ниже: вместо ссылки я сделал "кнопкой" обычную div с картинкой внутри. И в ее функции-обработчике клика я открываю "всплывашку" fancybox.

```js
$(".fancybox").on('click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
      href: $(this).data('href')
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>


<div class="fancybox" data-href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></div>
```